# how to determine which dimension 1,2 or 3 is changed in a table's modifiedField method?

Tags: axapta, x++

Am stuck in one place. I want to catch dimension[1] field's modified event using modifiedField method of PurchTable.

Am not able to determine the syntax for it. Can anyone please help ??

The general syntax we use under modifiedField method is as shown below.

```
case fieldnum(tableName, fieldname):
//DO you coding here
break;
```

Can anyone help me how to find fieldname of dimension[1] or how to write the above code for dimension[1].

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're using AX 2009, and if I recall, it's this style:

`fieldId2Ext(fieldNum(VendTrans, Dimension), 1)`

Answer (score 0):

First of all no need to find field name for dimension[1] no use of it, that was my wrong assumption.

And as answered by Alex and Jan the code will look like as follows,

```
switch(_fieldId)
{
    ...

    fieldId2Ext(fieldNum(VendTrans, Dimension), 1):
    //DO you coding here
    break;


    fieldId2Ext(fieldNum(VendTrans, Dimension), 2):
    //DO you coding here
    break;


    fieldId2Ext(fieldNum(VendTrans, Dimension), 3):
    //DO you coding here
    break;

    ...

    default: 
    break;
}
```